# How can I stress test a command line tool?

Tags: command-line

I'd like to try to stress-test a PHP script I've written, which accesses the filesystem, to see how it copes with load and parallel access.

I'd like to run this script `x` times in `y` different processes parallelly.

Is there a tool for this?

Comment: `echo {0..$x} | xargs -n 1 -P $y php yourscript.php` might be a start

Comment: @frostschutz Excellent, thanks. Can you add this as an answer?

Comment: There is also `parallel` from moreutils.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xargs` allows easy parallel processing. Here is an example (which assumes that your version of xargs supports the `-0` switch, which is *not* a POXIX requirement. If portability is an issue, simply use `echo` and drop the `-0`).

```
maxruns=2000
instances=50
printf '%s\0' {1..$maxruns} | xargs -0 -I, -n 1 -P $instances <program>
```

`printf` outputs the numbers from 1 to 2000 delimited by NULL characters. This is piped to `xargs`. The `-0` option notifies `xargs` that the values are delimited by a NULL characters instead of whitespace. The `-I` switch replaces the following character (a comma, can be any character sequence) with the input value. Since the input values are the numbers, which we don't need, and there is no other comma in the command line, the input is simply discarded. `-n 1` provides a maximum of one argument to `<program>`. `-P 50` runs no more than 50 instances of `<program>` at a time.